# Add text to word table in c# using word interop

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I am using Word.Interop in c# to inject data into a word document whch serves as a template for me.
This document has a table I wish to fill.
like this:
[image]

I am inserting the text like this (simpilified):

```
String text = "1" + "\t" + "2" + "\t" ; //Etc..
```

But this is not working.

Any idea how I should do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work. If you want to create a new table in a word document, set a bookmark in the document where you want the table to be created, then create the table as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w1702h4a.aspx

If you have an existing fixed table in the document, place custom document properties in the cells, then set their values like this:

```
thedocument.CustomDocumentProperties["NameOfTheCustomProperty"].Value = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for yor answer. It is an existing table. Could you please explain how can I set the costum propery in the table (in word)? Also, is it possible to insert pictures to the cells like this?

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/view-or-change-the-properties-for-an-office-file-HA010354245.aspx#_View_or_create

Comment: As for the image...no you need to word with ranges or bookmarks: http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2008/07/17/opening-and-inserting-a-picture-in-word-document-programmatically-using-c/